# Javascript Tinder like swiping but in a carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im trying to create a component on my web app. Which shows items in a caroussel where you can remove or like those items with swiping to left or right. Kinda like Tinder but difference is tinder are card stacks i want them in a caroussel.

I tried many different options none seems to be working. Any idea how i can achieve this?

Comment: can you share some code that you have tried or a fiddle ..?

Comment: Does "swiping" here rotate the carousel, or remove the carousel slide? What it your desired UX exactly? Once removed, do you mean removed from the carousel? Once liked, does it remain in the carousel?

Comment: Use hammer.js it provides the features you want. Other option will be using swiper.js

Comment: @EdmundReed The desired UX is: swiping up and down should rotate the carousel. Swiping right will remove the carousel slide. Swiping left will like the carousel slide and it will remain in the carousel.

Comment: @sfcdb Do you really need a carousel for that? It seems you have enough with basic scrolling (for the vertical part at least)

Comment: @sfcdb I understand what you mean, and it makes sense to me, sorry I cant help though.